# Table Filtering Using Big List

Tags: oracle, performance, select

Briefly, I am trying to filter a table using conditions plus a list of items in Oracle. In detail,
I have a reporting table which has millons of records. I would like to filter it using external lists which might include more than 1000 lines of fields from the record table. (Obviously, I especially said 1000, because `in clause` in Oracle has the limit of 1000 items). So my question is; How can I effectively filter a huge table using another big list.

Comment: One workaround for the limit of a 1000 values is to use a multi-column IN condition. `where (1, the_column) in ( (1,100), (1, 200), (1, 300) )` - but that won't be very efficient either.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I effectively filter a huge table using another big list?

Just `JOIN` the big table to list.

Just make sure your list is a table format:

- External Table
- Global Temporary Table
- APEX Collection (for APEX apps)
- an SQL collection (variable)

  - PL/SQL collection (18c+)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will use this in my Hibernate + Spring application and the list will be submitted from UI. I think none of these will fully get my requirement done. I think I will need to tweak it on UI via paging data tables :). And cut down some filter functions. All I can do is this now :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a temporary table then store the values in smaller lists.

then join your main table with the temporary table on the appropriate column to filter the data.

E.g.

```
-- Create a temporary table
CREATE GLOBAL temporary table temp_ids (id int);
```

-- Insert your IDs into the temporary table

```
-- Join the main table with the temporary table to filter the data
SELECT t.*
FROM your_table t
JOIN temp_ids tmp ON t.id = tmp.id;
```